# Flask learning project : Adding new input fields to the existing form of current html page and saving data into mysql database

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I have built a dynamic form where i am having 2 input fields(name, and email). on click of submit it stores data into MySQL db. Also, I can add more input fields in the same form.

this is on my flask project for my learning purpose.

let's say I am adding 2 new fields. so that will be 2 plus 2 total 4 fields. after filling all 4 fields in the form. I want to submit data into MySQL DB.

how to do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dynamic Fields</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  <style>
    body {
    background-color: #c1cce0;
    font-family: 'Jost',sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    }
    h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #232c3d;
    }

    .container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 40px 0px rgba(47,47,47,.1);
    }

    input[type="text"]{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    background: none;
    width: 274px;
    color: black;
    }

    input[type="text"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    }

    input[type="Submit"]{
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type="Submit"]:hover{
    background: #2691d9;
    color: #e9f4fb;
    transition: .5s;
    }

    .controls {
    width: 294px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    }

    .add {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .remove {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .controls button i{
    margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .remove:hover, .add:hover{
    background: #2691d9;
    color: #e9f4fb;
    transition: .5s;
    }
  </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form action="" method="POST">
      <div id="formfield">
        <input type="text" name="text" class="text" size="50" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input type="text" name="text" class="text" size="50" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="text" name="text" class="text" size="50" placeholder="Optional Field">
      </div>
      <input name="submit" type="Submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="add" onclick="add()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add</button>
        <button class="remove" onclick="remove()"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var formfield = document.getElementById('formfield');

function add(){
  var newField = document.createElement('input');
  newField.setAttribute('type','text');
  newField.setAttribute('name','text');
  newField.setAttribute('class','text');
  newField.setAttribute('siz',50);
  newField.setAttribute('placeholder','Optional Field');
  formfield.appendChild(newField);
}

function remove(){
  var input_tags = formfield.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if(input_tags.length > 2) {
    formfield.removeChild(input_tags[(input_tags.length) - 1]);
  }
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to store the user input data of optional fields but. It only stores data from database-mapped input fields. it does not store the optional field.

for example. let's say a user might have 2 email accounts. for that, I am adding a new input field by clicking 'add' on my HTML code. but how to store them

Comment: you can add a same class name to existing field and newly added. then in javascript you can use `element.classList.add`. ref: https://www.scaler.com/topics/classlist-javascript/